# How to fix what emerge is complaining about?

Tags: linux, package-management, gentoo

I have a Gentoo 13 system built from sources following the handbook. Its in the `default/linux/amd64/13.0` configuration. I use the system to test other software on the platform. Software testing is the only reason this VM exists.

```
$ eselect profile list
Available profile symlink targets:
  [1]   default/linux/amd64/13.0 *
  [2]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/selinux
  [3]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop
  [4]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/gnome
  [5]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/gnome/systemd
  [6]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/kde
  [7]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/kde/systemd
  [8]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/plasma
  [9]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/plasma/systemd
  [10]  default/linux/amd64/13.0/developer
  [11]  default/linux/amd64/13.0/no-multilib
  [12]  default/linux/amd64/13.0/systemd
  [13]  default/linux/amd64/13.0/x32
  ...
```

Naively, I tried to set the profile to GNOME. I did not realize its basically incompatible with Gentoo (why is it even a choice?) and now the package manager is mostly broken. I set the profile back to what I used during the installation but it did not fix the problems introduced when attempting to use the GNOME profile.

`emerge` spews lots of messages (shown below), but I'm not sure what's wrong or how to fix it. I keep looping back to `emerge --update --newuse --deep @world` because `emerge` repeatedly tells me to run it, but it does not appear to fix anything since the same problems are continually reported.

How can I determine what is causing the problems, and how can I fix it?

I realize *"How to fix what emerge is complaining about?"* is a crummy title. But I have no idea what is wrong, so I don't know what to say the problem is or ask how to fix it.

---

Related, here are some resources that have not been helpful in fixing the problems with `emerge`. I'm not even sure if the blocked packages are the problem or a symptom of the problem.

- [Gentoo | Blocked Packages](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Working/Portage#Blocked_packages)
- [emerge complains about blocked packages: what do I do?](https://superuser.com/q/303386/173513)
- [Gentoo Cheat Sheet](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Gentoo_Cheat_Sheet)

---

```
# emerge --update --newuse --deep @world

 * IMPORTANT: 1 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild     U  ] sys-libs/glibc-2.22-r4 [2.21-r2]
[ebuild   R    ] sys-libs/ncurses-5.9-r5  USE="-gpm*" 
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/expat-2.1.1-r2 [2.1.0-r5]
[ebuild  N     ] app-arch/lz4-0_p131  USE="{-test} -valgrind" ABI_X86="(64) -32 (-x32)" 
[ebuild     U  ] sys-apps/debianutils-4.7 [4.4]
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/libffi-3.2.1 [3.0.13-r1]
[ebuild   R    ] sys-libs/ncurses-5.9-r99  USE="-gpm*" 
[ebuild     U  ] sys-libs/cracklib-2.9.6 [2.9.1-r1]
[ebuild     U  ] sys-libs/timezone-data-2016e [2015g]
[ebuild     U  ] app-portage/portage-utils-0.62 [0.56]
[ebuild     U  ] sys-devel/m4-1.4.17 [1.4.16]
[ebuild     U  ] app-arch/unzip-6.0_p20 [6.0-r3]
[ebuild     U  ] virtual/acl-0-r2 [0-r1] ABI_X86="(64%*) -32% (-x32)" 
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/libksba-1.3.4 [1.3.3]
[ebuild     U  ] sys-devel/gettext-0.19.7 [0.19.4]
[ebuild     U  ] app-eselect/eselect-python-20140125-r1 [20111108]
[ebuild     U  ] net-dns/libidn-1.33 [1.30]
[ebuild  NS    ] app-text/docbook-xml-dtd-4.5-r1 [4.1.2-r6, 4.2-r2, 4.3-r1, 4.4-r2]
[ebuild   R    ] sys-kernel/linux-headers-4.3  CROSSCOMPILE_OPTS="-headers-only%" 
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2h-r2 [1.0.2g-r2] USE="sslv3%* -sslv2%" 
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-MIME-Base64-3.140.0-r1 
[ebuild     U  ] dev-util/intltool-0.51.0-r1 [0.50.2-r1]
[ebuild     U  ] dev-perl/Net-SSLeay-1.720.0-r1 [1.650.0-r1] USE="-examples% (-libressl) -minimal% {-test%}" 
[ebuild     U  ] sys-apps/sysvinit-2.88-r9 [2.88-r7]
[ebuild     U  ] sys-apps/texinfo-6.1 [5.2]
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/libxslt-1.1.29 [1.1.28-r5]
[ebuild     U  ] dev-scheme/guile-1.8.8-r2 [1.8.8-r1] USE="readline%*" 
[ebuild   R    ] sys-apps/groff-1.22.2  L10N="-ja%" LINGUAS="(-ja%)" 
[ebuild     U  ] sys-apps/kmod-22 [21]
[ebuild   R    ] dev-lang/python-2.7.10-r1  USE="-sqlite*" 
[ebuild   R    ] app-crypt/pinentry-0.9.5  USE="-gnome-keyring* -gtk*" 
[ebuild     U  ] dev-util/gtk-doc-am-1.25 [1.24]
[ebuild   R    ] www-client/w3m-0.5.3-r5  USE="-X* -gpm* -gtk*" L10N="-ja%" LINGUAS="(-ja%)" 
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/libpcre-8.38-r1 [8.38]
[ebuild     U  ] app-editors/nano-2.5.3 [2.4.3]
[ebuild     U  ] net-libs/gnutls-3.3.24 [3.3.17.1]
[ebuild   R    ] sys-fs/eudev-3.1.5  USE="-introspection*" 
[ebuild   R    ] app-crypt/gnupg-2.0.28  USE="-ldap* -usb*" 
[ebuild     U  ] sys-apps/portage-2.2.28 [2.2.26]
[ebuild     U  ] app-admin/perl-cleaner-2.20 [2.19]
[ebuild  N     ] sys-apps/systemd-226-r2  USE="acl kdbus kmod lz4 pam seccomp ssl (-apparmor) -audit -cryptsetup -curl -elfutils -gcrypt -gnuefi -http -idn -importd -lzma -nat -policykit -qrcode (-selinux) -sysv-utils {-test} -vanilla -xkb" ABI_X86="(64) -32 (-x32)" 
[ebuild     U  ] sys-apps/dbus-1.10.8-r1 [1.10.6] USE="systemd* -X* -user-session%" 
[ebuild  N     ] sys-apps/gentoo-systemd-integration-6 
[ebuild   R    ] sys-auth/pambase-20150213  USE="systemd* -consolekit* -gnome-keyring*" 
[ebuild   R    ] net-misc/openssh-7.2_p2  USE="-X* -ldap*" 
[ebuild     U  ] dev-libs/glib-2.46.2-r3 [2.46.2-r2] USE="-dbus*" 
[ebuild  N     ] x11-misc/shared-mime-info-1.4  USE="{-test}" 
[blocks B      ] sys-apps/gentoo-systemd-integration ("sys-apps/gentoo-systemd-integration" is blocking sys-fs/eudev-3.1.5)
[blocks B      ] sys-fs/eudev ("sys-fs/eudev" is blocking sys-apps/gentoo-systemd-integration-6)
[blocks B      ] sys-fs/eudev ("sys-fs/eudev" is blocking sys-apps/systemd-226-r2)
[blocks B      ] sys-apps/systemd ("sys-apps/systemd" is blocking sys-fs/eudev-3.1.5)

 * Error: The above package list contains packages which cannot be
 * installed at the same time on the same system.

  (sys-apps/systemd-226-r2:0/2::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by
    >=sys-apps/systemd-207 required by (sys-apps/gentoo-systemd-integration-6:0/0::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)
    sys-apps/systemd:0= required by (sys-apps/dbus-1.10.8-r1:0/0::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)
    >=sys-apps/systemd-204[pam] required by (sys-auth/pambase-20150213:0/0::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)

  (sys-fs/eudev-3.1.5:0/0::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by
    >=sys-fs/eudev-1.3 required by (virtual/udev-215:0/0::gentoo, installed)
    >=sys-fs/eudev-1.3:0/0[abi_x86_32(-)?,abi_x86_64(-)?,abi_x86_x32(-)?,abi_mips_n32(-)?,abi_mips_n64(-)?,abi_mips_o32(-)?,abi_ppc_32(-)?,abi_ppc_64(-)?,abi_s390_32(-)?,abi_s390_64(-)?,static-libs?] (>=sys-fs/eudev-1.3:0/0[abi_x86_64(-)]) required by (virtual/libudev-215-r1:0/1::gentoo, installed)


For more information about Blocked Packages, please refer to the following
section of the Gentoo Linux x86 Handbook (architecture is irrelevant):

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Working/Portage#Blocked_packages


The following USE changes are necessary to proceed:
 (see "package.use" in the portage(5) man page for more details)
# required by net-misc/openssh-7.2_p2::gentoo[ssl,-static]
# required by virtual/ssh-0::gentoo[-minimal]
# required by @system
# required by @world (argument)
>=dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2h-r2 bindist

Use --autounmask-write to write changes to config files (honoring
CONFIG_PROTECT). Carefully examine the list of proposed changes,
paying special attention to mask or keyword changes that may expose
experimental or unstable packages.
```

Comment: Have you tried doing what it proposes? Running emerge with `--autounmask-write` to change the config files in `/etc/portage/` (and calling `etc-update` after that)?

Comment: @Tim - No. I have not gotten past the previous steps of troubleshooting using the wiki at [Gentoo | Blocked Packages](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Working/Portage#Blocked_packages). Trying the command `sudo emerge --autounmask-write` after your suggestion results in an error with usage. And `sudo emerge --autounmask-write --update --newuse --deep @world` results in the same error. This tool sucks...

Comment: @Tim - Maybe an easier path is to go back to the original configuration. Do you know how to tell the package manager to delete all packages and binaries that are not part of ***`default/linux/amd64/13.0`***. That's kind of what i am trying to achieve, but this tool is so damn frustrating and can't get it to do it.

Comment: Looking closer at the error message: Is `virtual/udev`compiled with or without the `systemd` useflag? If it has the flag, it should not depend on sys-fs/eudev. If it hasn't this is inconsistent with all other packages. In the latter case it should appear in the list of packages to merge, but doesn't. So you must have set it differently somewhere in your `package.use` files. Try to reinstall it with the correct flags. Also the news item mentioned in the top of your message may be helpful.

Comment: There are no packages in `default/linux/amd64` (or any other profiles), only configurations. You can uninstall packages that no other package depends on via `emerge --depclean`, but you should not do this until the command you are trying to run works (because it may remove packages that the system still needs, assuming their functionality would be provided by other packages that should be installed but are not yet).